# Reasons behind why abstract and strictfp keywords cannot be used together in a method declaration?

Tags: java, abstract-methods, strictfp

I'm reading SCJP by katherine sierra. 
I understand that abstract and final keywords cannot be used together because they contradict each other as explained in the book.

However, I don't understand why strictfp and abstract keywords cannot be used together.
I don't know how the strictfp keyword exactly works in Java yet.

In my thoughts, one could declare an abstract strictfp method, have a subclass, and implement that method in the "strictfp way".

What is the reason these keywords don't get along well together ? 
**EDIT**
I've double checked the book and it surely says

> Because interface methods are abstract, they cannot be marked final,
>   strictfp , or native .

from SCJP by Katherine Sierra. page 21.

Also my IDE(Eclipse Juno) says I can't use abstract and strictfp keywords together.
Hmmm, why not though ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Katherine Sierra was probably talking about abstract methods. It would make no sense to make an abstract method `strictfp` because an abstract method just provides a method signature (and throws clause if any), to use it we need to override it in a subclass with a concrete method and this method will have its own modifiers which will override its parent method's modifiers. That is, methods do not inherit modifiers.

Note that it's not only `sctriptfp`, but no modifiers are allowed on abstract methods except `public` and `protected`. You'll get a compile-time error if you try.

Comment: Interesting, where could I find some documents that say an overriding method would not inherit modifiers ?  Methods do inherit access modifiers, right ?

Comment: All answers are in JLS. Methods do not inherit access modifier, if you did not specify a modifier method gets a default one - package private

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev, But we can have method body in interfaces in Java 8.  So why isn't the `strictfp` allowed for interfaces?

Answer (score 3):

Hope you already got your answer by now if not then it may be useful for you.

I have encountered a similar question asked in a forum.

The reason why `abstract` and `strictfp` can't sit  together in the method declaration is because `abstract` says the method must not be implemented by the current class and it must be implemented by the concrete subclass and `strictfp` says the method should be implemented (should have a body) by the class where `strictfp` is used. So in this case both key words contradict with each other hence both are not allowed together in method declarations.

But it is absolutely legal to use `abstract` and `strictfp` before class. Something like

```
public abstract strictfp class MyAbstractClass{}      //is ok
```

If you declare strictfp in a abstract  class then all its method is going to be strictfp by default. Remember all the concrete methods in side the class not the abstract methods.

Run the example given below and see the OP:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
public abstract strictfp class AbstractStrictfp 
{
     public   abstract void abstractMethod();
     public   void concreteMethod(){};

     public static void main(String args[]){
          Method methods[] = AbstractStrictfp.class.getMethods();
          for(Method method : methods){
              System.out.println("Method Name::"+method.getName());
                     System.out.println("Modifiers::"+Modifier.toString(method.getModifiers()));
              System.out.println();

          }
     }
}
```